# Cross-platform usage of URI geo scheme

Tags: geo, url-scheme

I am trying to find a way to embed a link to open a navigation to geocoordinates (lat + lon) via the uri geo scheme.

However, it seems not all platforms are currently supported. The requirement is to let the user choose its own provider (Google Maps / Apple Maps / other navigation app).

How do I create a cross-platform link which works at least with Windows Chrome, Apple iPhone and Android phones?

If absolutely required, the links may change dynamically by user agent.

I tried this scheme, but it just opens a blank new tab for Chrome on Windows without anything defined:

`<a href="geo:lat,lon">Start navigation</a>`

How can I make sure as a fallback in such cases at least any mapping application opens?

Is this even technically possible already or is the geo uri scheme really that inaccessible currently?

Answer (score 0):

The `geo:` scheme is not widely supported; as far as I can tell it only works on Android. But google maps and apple maps both support Universal links (Google calls them App links) which will open the app if it's installed, otherwise it opens a website. Here's what that looks like in practice:

```
openMaps(lat: number, lng: number, pref: string): void {
    const params = encodeURIComponent(address);
    if (pref === 'google') {
        const mapsLink = `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${lat},${lng}`;
        window.open(mapsLink, '_system');
    } else if (pref === 'apple') {
        const mapsLink = `https://maps.apple.com/?q=${lat},${lng};
        window.open(mapsLink, '_system');
    }
}
```

You can also pass an address string instead of lat/long